How to make gcc emit assembler code in c++ static function wrapped in asm volatile?
The goal is to call WaitReps(x) where x>0 and have the thread execute x repetitions of 'pause/dec ecx'. The caller is a pinned thread. The code:
class WaitUtil {                                                                                                        
public:                                                                                                                 
  static void WaitReps(u_int64_t count);
};                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                        
inline                                                                                                                  
void WaitUtil::WaitReps(u_int64_t count) {
  // repeat until ecx 0                                                                              
  asm volatile (                                                                                                        
    ".rep               \n\t"                                                                                           
    "pause              \n\t"                                                                                           
    "dec ecx            \n\t"                                                                                           
    ".endr              \n\t"                                                                                           
    :                                                                                                                   
    : "c" (count)                                                                                                       
  );                                                                                                                    
}  

The file is compiled with g++ -O3 -march=native ... with LTO. And darn it ... no matter what I do the code is missing in the executable. compiling -O0 doesn't help. neither does disabling LTO. objdump -d on task shows no pause instructions.
I thought volatile was supposed to tell g++/gasm hands off. I've also tried putting function in a .cpp file and removing inline.
I can confirm by inspecting the temp files (-save-temps) g++ makes the code was in there until something stripped it. Here's a call from the task with count 4000000 from the .s file:
    movl    $4000000, %ecx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    salq    $32, %rdx
    orq %rdx, %rdi
#APP
# 22 "syncthread_waitutil.h" 1
    .rep               
    pause              
    dec ecx            
    .endr              

How do I get the compile to emit the indicated code?
Thank you
Bonus: passing the repetition count and decrementing ecx could be avoided if I could figure out how to pass a constant to .rept. But this is nice to have only:
  asm volatile (                                                                                                        
    ".rept %[cnt]       \n\t"                                                                                           
    "pause              \n\t"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ".endr              \n\t"                                                                                           
    :                                                                                                                   
    : "cnt" "r" (count)                                                                                                       
  );                                                                                                                    


I think I over engineered the solution. I also confused .rep and .endr pseudo instructions to real Intel x86 rep instructions which are not preceeded by a dot. It's not possible to rep pause instructions.
This does what I wanted, and the code is emitted as desired:
inline                                                                                                                  
void WaitUtil::WaitReps(u_int64_t count) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
  while(count) {                                                                                                        
    asm volatile ("pause;");                                                                                            
    --count;                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                     
}


That works, but please don't abuse the pause instruction for timed waits.  That's not what it's meant for.  Use the nanosleep system call instead.

nanosleep is too coarse grained. my application is for high frequency trading. I'm trying to get packets out under 1us end-to-end from app perspective.

@fuz: My answer on How to calculate time for an asm delay loop on x86 linux? has code to spin on RDTSC waiting for a deadline, usable for delays too short for a system call.  (You need to know the TSC frequency, though.)  i.e. it emulates tpause on CPUs without the waitpkg feature, without the power saving

@PeterCordes That's probably a much better solution.  pause should be used with care, as it is about waiting for other threads to do things rather than delaying the current thread.  It may not give a consistent delay and it's possible that it has side effects on other threads' performance.

@fuz: On a hyperthreaded CPU, pause should help the other thread's performance by taking fewer front-end cycles (and less back-end uops).  But yes, it yields the front-end for about 5 cycles on AMD (and Intel before Skylake), vs. about 100 cycles on later Intel.  (And could be different in future or on other interesting CPUs or emulators.)  You could include a pause in a rdtsc deadline spin-wait to reduce power and be more SMT-friendly, at the expense of maybe sometimes waiting longer past the deadline.

@cordes thanks for the link. I might steal and idea or two from there for my `Calibrate' routine.

You can use an i constraint to force an immediate and the c modifier to print it in such a way that .rept works:
asm volatile (
    ".rept %c0\n\t"
    "pause\n\t
    ".endr"
    :: "i"(cnt));`

This then just works when compiling with optimisations.  Without optimisations it fails to compile though.

thank you for suggestion but that makes a really big .tsk for larger values of cnt ... it really emits cnt pause or nops in file.

@fwefew4t4tg Isn't that what you wanted?
